# Java: I want to get TextField value when I clicked a button. How to do it?

Tags: java, button, applet, awt, textfield

```
public Monster createCharacterScene() {
    String name;
    TextField nameTextField = new TextField();
    nameTextField.setLocation(65, 50);
    nameTextField.setSize(60, 10);
    Button myButton = new Button("OK");
    myButton.setLocation(25, 50);
    myButton.setSize(30, 40);
    add(myButton);
    add(nameTextField);
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            name = nameTextField.getText();
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

I can't do it like this. They says "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final". Is there alternative way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

PS. I using applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read this value directly in `createCharacterScene()` method. Because it's unknown yet. The only thing you can do is to define a eventHandler, that will be triggered, on key press.

```
Consumer<String> nameConsumer = text -> { /*You will handle event here*/};
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            nameConsumer.apply(nameTextField.getText());
        }
    });
```

The cheaper version would be to use a small workaround for final modifier:

```
final String[] nameHolder = new String[1];
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            nameHolder[0] = nameTextField.getText();
        }
    });
```

Here nameHolder will initially hold null, but when someone will trigger the event, it's value will be set, so you need to check if value is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

make `name`a pseudo-final :

```
  final String[] name = new String[1];
```

and access it this way  :

```
 name[0] = nameTextField.getText();
```